Does layzer zero preserve token functionality across chains?
I'm evaluating layzer zero and I am aware that it can wrap erc-20 tokens or create new ofts.
However, I'd like to know whether if my existing erc-20 token has freeze functionality (can freeze an address' funds) and I wrap it using layzer zero oft standard, then burn it on ethereum and mint it on another chain, would I still be able to freeze the token on the destination chain?

The point is that you deploy a separate contract on each network (or wrap an existing one). The contracts are completely separate. Whatever you do on one chain is not, by default, reflected on other chains in any way.
What LZ offers is basically easy (and secure?) bridging.
If you freeze assets on one chain, it has no effect on other chains. If you want to freeze on another chain as well, you have to explicitly do it on that chain as well.
If assets are frozen on the source chain, they can't be transferred (nor burned), and therefore can't be bridged to another network through LZ bridge.
